# Allow raw HTML in LaTeX code with Pandoc

Tags: html, latex, pandoc

I know including raw HTML is possible in Markdown documents with Pandoc, so I was wondering if there was a way to allow it in LaTeX documents.

Pandoc converts lower than and greater than characters to HTML entities when included in a LaTeX document (even when inside a verbatim). it makes perfect sens but it's not what I want.

Comment: escape the characters

Comment: It doesn't work. You can try it out online [here](https://pandoc.org/try/?text=%5Cnewcommand%7B%5Cspan%7D%5B1%5D%7B%5C%3Cspan%5C%3E%231%5C%3C%2Fspan%5C%3E%7D%0A%0AThis+is+a+%5C%3Cspan%5C%3Etest%5C%3C%2Fspan%5C%3E%0A%0AThis+is+another+%5Cspan%7Btest%7D%0A&from=latex&to=html5) : the characters are deleted altogether.

Comment: I was hoping someone would have worked out how to support ``\begin{rawhtml}...\end{rawhtml}`` with pandoc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to use a specially-marked `verbatim` environment, which can then be transformed into the desired target format via a [Lua filter](https://pandoc.org/lua-filters.html). E.g., add a `%%%html` tag as the first line of a verbatim environment, then insert the HTML which you'd like to preserve:

```
\begin{verbatim}
%%%html
<aside>Embedding raw HTML can be helpful</aside>
\end{verbatim}
```

Pandoc will read this as a normal code block, but we want a raw HTML block. We use a filter a filter to convert it:

```lua
function CodeBlock(cb)
  local rawHtml = cb.text:match('^%s*%%%%%%html\n(.*)')
  if rawHtml then
    return pandoc.RawBlock('html', rawHtml)
  end
end
```

Save the above into a file and use it as the argument of pandoc's `--lua-filter` option.

Comment: This is awesome! I noticed that verbatim behaves like a block and has the tendency to close paragraphs, which is not great when I want to insert inline elements within a paragraph, but now that I know where to look I should be able to sort this out by myself. I suppose I can aso modify the behavior of \texttt.